# How remove subsection for a specific frame in latex-beamer

Tags: frame-title, frame, subsection

hi guys I hope you are doing well I'm building a presentation using beamer latex, and I want to remove the bar in the header where the name of the subsection is shown just for specific frames

these are some frames that I wanna remove subsection title from it \titlepage and \tableofcontents and some specific frames

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you understand now!